# Managing multiple users getting work assignments in SQL Server 2008R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, concurrency, queue

I have a SQL database that has two tables that hold a queue of work to be done and the history of that work:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WorkQueue](
    [WorkQueueID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [BatchID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AdHocProjectID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TaskID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CreateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [CompletedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [AlertMessage] [varchar](1024) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_WorkQueue] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [WorkQueueID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WorkQueueHistory](
    [WorkQueueHistoryID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [WorkQueueID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EmployeeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [BatchBoxID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [StartTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [EndTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [PercentageCompleted] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FinishedTask] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [comment] [varchar](255) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_WorkQueueHistory] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [WorkQueueHistoryID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The WorkQueue table contains tasks from batches (Jobs) that need to be worked. Users insert into the WorkQueueHistory table when they start working on a job, and when they finish working on a job that row in the WorkQueueHistory table is updated with their end time and the FinishedTask bit is set if that task was indeed completed 100%.

My question is what is the best way to prevent two users from starting the same task? Right now we don't have enough users for this to be a problem, but as things grow I know there is going to be a concurrency issue if I don't address this.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `transaction` with the appropriate isolation level set.

See http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SQLTransactions.aspx

```
begin tran

    -- select next job to do

    -- update job as started

commit
```

Comment: That seems fairly simple and makes sense. Do I need to do anything special with the isolation level?

Comment: It depends :) Read around the subject and consider your situation and data model eg: - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2011/02/20/concurrency-series-basics-of-transaction-isolation-levels.aspx .

Comment: I have read both of the articles you linked. They are a bit over my head, but I get the basics. I have to select from WorkQueue to find a qualifying WorkQueueID to insert into WorkQueuehistory. I am not seeing how this would prevent two sessions from inserting the same WorkQueueID into the WorkQueueHistory table. I understand I need to lock the WorkQueue row I find until I insert into the WorkQueueHistory but I just don't understand that yet.

Comment: @zulelord It depends. How do you determine what the next work item is?

Comment: Its a rather complex query, but the basic of it is I select a WorkQueueID by selecting the workqueue table for a certain taskid and batchid and join the workqueuehistory where there is either no history the endtime is not null and the finished bit is 0. That way I am getting a workqueueid that has never been worked, or is not currently being worked on. (Something being worked on would have an endtime that was null)